# Get the index of the first element in an array with value greater than x

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
var array = [400, 4000, 400, 400, 4000];
```

How can I get the index of the first element with value greater than 400?

**Note:** While making sure this question was unique, I came across questions asking this same problem- but for different programming languages.
If there are duplicates of my question that apply to JS, I'd really want to see them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) here

check this snippet

```js
var array = [400, 4000, 400, 400, 4000];
var index=array.findIndex(function(number) {
  return number > 400;
});
console.log(index);
```

Comment: or in ES6 `var index = array.findIndex(n => n > 400);`

Comment: @RobG so it is - I misread the MDN page as saying it was in ES5

Comment: It's a little confusing that the edition numbers are one off the year number. Perhaps they should skip a year so they align. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple `for` loop and check each element.

```js
var array = [400, 4000, 400, 400, 4000];

var result;

for(var i=0, l=array.length; i<l; i++){
  if(array[i] > 400){
    result = i;
    break;
  }
}

if(typeof result !== 'undefined'){
  console.log('number greater than 400 found at array index: ' + result);
} else {
  console.log('no number greater than 400 found in the given arrry.');
}
```

Read up: [`for` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [0, 0, 3, 5, 6];
var x = 5;
var i = 0;
while (array[i] <= x) {
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [0, 0, 3, 5, 6];
let x     = 5;
let i     = 0;
for (; i<array.length && array[i] <= x; i++);
```

If there is an element greater than x, this returns the index of the first one. Otherwise it returns the length of the array.