# How to find a first occurrence of double digit number

Tags: javascript, math, digits

So, I am pushing elements into array through prompt until getting 0. After that I am trying to find the first double digit number. For example if the array is `[2,3,55,0]` my program should return 55.

```js
function findFirstDouble() {
 var niz = []
 var a = 1;
 for (var i = 1; a != 0; i++) {
  var unos = parseInt(prompt("Enter number :"))
  niz.push(unos)
  a = unos
 }
 alert(niz);
 for (var i = 0; i < niz.length; i++) {
  if (niz[i] / 10 > 0 && niz[i] / 100 == 0) {
   console.log(niz[i]); 
   break;
  }
  else {
   alert("No double digit numbers!")
   break;
  }
 }
}
findFirstDouble();
```

Comment: Convert to a string and try length property==2

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does *anything* happen? Errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: @eugensunic or check if the number is `>= 10` and `<= 99`?

Comment: @Pointy sure...

Comment: Look at [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603036/get-the-index-of-the-first-element-in-an-array-with-value-greater-than-x). This question is essentially answered here. Just exclude the `findIndex` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I think you are looking for.

I omitted the array filling part.

Why would you do any kind of division if you just need to check every number and if the first one matches the criteria then you've got your double digit number hence exit the loop with **break** or **return** keyword.

```
var niz = [1, 2, 55, 13];
for (var i = 0; i < niz.length; i++) {
    if (niz[i] > 9 && niz[i] < 100) {
        console.log('Pronadeni broj je:', niz[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also convert to string:  `if (niz[i].toString().length===2){ // your number }`

Answer (score 2):

Please use built in `js` function `find`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Here is the solution

```
// I assume that you already have an array   
const niz = [2,3,55,0]
const firstDoubleDigit = niz.find(num => num < 100 && num >= 10)
console.log(firstDoubleDigit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way without math is just to convert it to a string.

```js
const data = [2,3,55,0];

const res = data.findIndex(n=>`${n}`.length===2);

console.log(res > -1 ? "Exists at position " + res : "Doesn't exist");
```

Mathematically:

```js
const data = [2,111,3,55,0];

const res = data.find(n=>n<100&&n>9);

console.log(res ? "Exists " + res : "Doesn't exist");
```

Comment: Here problem is a college entrance subject or high school problem therefore this solution isn't convenient I guess from her perspective... but hey +1 I like it.